# Триггер MySQL AFTER UPDATE срабатывает при вставке записи в таблицу

Tags: mysql

Почему AFTER UPDATE триггер срабатывает при вставке новой записи в таблицу?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `afterStatusChanged` AFTER UPDATE ON `orders` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE notify_status INT;
SELECT user.notify_status INTO notify_status FROM user WHERE user.user_id = NEW.user_id AND user.notify = '1';
IF notify_status > 0 THEN
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO notifications (notify_dateDelivered, notify_title, notify_body, notify_userID) VALUES (NOW(), '', CONCAT('Ваш статус: ', NEW.order_status), NEW.user_id);
  END; 
  END IF;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Запрос:

```
INSERT INTO orders (user_id, order_date, order_status, order_subj, order_cost) VALUES ('$user_id', NOW(), 'В обработке', '$order_subj', '$order_cost')
```

Comment: Ну, тут "либо что-то случилось, либо одно из двух". Подробности?

Comment: Запрос на вставку и текст триггера в студию. Допускаю, что ODKU.

Comment: Обновил вопрос..

Comment: Структура таблицы и запрос на вставку? Есть ли триггер ON INSERT?

Comment: триггера on insert для этой таблицы нет!

Comment: Так все-таки, запрос? Если @Akina прав и это ODKU?

Comment: Обновил вопрос..

Comment: Мдя... Была одна мысль. Проверил на практике - не подтвердилась. Есть подозрение, что сработку триггера вызывает какой-то другой запрос. Возможно - "скрытый" кодом PHP, например - обработчик событий, или неявно (через наследование) вызываемый метод класса. Вы пробовали в консоли мускула отдельно этот запрос на вставку выполнить? Также триггер срабатывает?